# How can I get the local system time zone as an IANA time zone ID on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, time-zone

I can get the Windows system local time zone as a *Windows* time zone identifier by passing the `/g` parameter to the `tzutil` utility.

For example:

```
C:\> tzutil /g
Pacific Standard Time
```

But how can I get the equivalent IANA time zone identifier, `America/Los_Angeles`?

Answer (score 3):

This can be done by calling the [`GetTimeZone`](https://docs.microsoft.com/uwp/api/windows.globalization.calendar.gettimezone) method on an instance of the UWP/WinRT class [`Windows.Globalization.Calendar`](https://docs.microsoft.com/uwp/api/windows.globalization.calendar) constructed with no parameters.

As a PowerShell one-liner:

```
PS C:\> [Windows.Globalization.Calendar,Windows.Globalization,ContentType=WindowsRuntime]::New().GetTimeZone()
America/Los_Angeles
```