# Why is Windows 11 getting my time zone wrong?

Tags: windows-11, time-zone, location

Windows 11 has recently started assigning the wrong time zone to two computers when the option to "set time zone automatically" is enabled.  When I disable this option, I can set the correct time zone, but immediately after I re-enable it, the time zone reverts to the incorrect one.

I would like to know if there are any logs that would enable me to diagnose this failure.

I assume that the logic is roughly as follows:

1. Physical location is determined from IP address or other indicators.
2. IANA time zone is determined from physical location.
3. Windows time zone is determined from IANA time zone as described at [How to translate between Windows and IANA time zones](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17348822/385844) (in particular as specified [here](https://github.com/unicode-org/cldr/blob/master/common/supplemental/windowsZones.xml)).

I've confirmed that the computer's location service is reporting the location correctly, and I've confirmed that the mapping in Windows zones.xml is correct.  I therefore suspect that the second step above is being performed incorrectly, and I would like to see whether that's the case.  If there is a log somewhere that traces the logical steps from location to time zone in any detail, that would help.

I noticed that there has been a [recent change to this aspect of Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/december-12-2023-kb5033118-os-build-20348-2159-0f37ecad-fb53-4209-a05b-5e2cd0feeb98).  This behavior seems to have started a few weeks after the update was installed, so I wouldn't think it's related, but on the other hand it's very recent, and I might have misunderstood something about the timing of the update.  In particular, if the update changed the resolution with which Windows identifies the IANA time zone, it could cause this behavior, as the incorrect time zone is between 5 and 15 km away in almost every direction.  The date of `C:\Windows\Globalization\Time Zone\tzautoupdate.dat` is 2023-12-12.  I assume that this is the shape file used to translate between locations and time zones, though it doesn't have any IANA names, so it's possible that the IANA-to-Windows step is pre-baked into that file.

Is there any way to get Windows to report the IANA time zone?  Is it possible to read or otherwise analyze `tzautoupdate.dat`?

Comment: Where is your IP address geographically located? You may use for that a service such as https://whatismyipaddress.com/.

Comment: Are you connected to an Active Directory domain? Are you behind a proxy?  Are you behind a VPN?

Comment: I assume that you have not only installed KB5033118 but have also installed KB5034129?  I also presume you are impacted by a change that happened in Netherlands time zone reclassification.

Comment: @harrymc I'm on a VPN.  The public IP address is six hours away, not in the time zone that Windows is choosing.  The IP address from my ISP is in the correct time zone -- the one that Windows had been choosing before a couple of weeks ago.

Comment: @Ramhound Yes to all of the above (AD, proxy, VPN).  They are company laptops.  My company has no facilities in the incorrect time zone, though.  I haven't checked what's going on with my personal laptop; I'll try tomorrow.  I don't see how adding territory to the Netherlands IANA time zone would change time zone detection for a computer that isn't in that time zone, but if that _is_ what's happening it ought to be possible to diagnose by examining the shape files.

Comment: @phoog -I would first contact the AD Administrator to see if there are any group policies that might explain the behavior you have witnessed. Additionally, I would make sure the geolocation of the VPN and Proxy is not the reason, for the incorrect time zone detection.I suspect you will find that either a domain level group policy is to blame or the VPN and/or proxy is to blame for this behavior. I cannot find any evidence that anyone is having problems with the changes associated with the modification to the Netherlands time zone. I also have no doubt Microsoft would have extensively tested it

Comment: @Ramhound Do you have any information on what exactly changed for the Dutch timezone? I'm an IT guy and Dutch, but this is the first time I have heard about this.

Comment: @Tonny - Read the release notes for the update in question (KB5033118). Microsoft updated the timezone for the Netherlands. Plenty of information to educate yourself. I just don’t have the bandwidth to explain the changes to a timezone that doesn’t effect me.

Comment: @Ramhound I normally don't go through the particulars of every individual KB release note (life's to short). But thank you for the KB number. I'll can find the info on my own now....
It is apparently just a shape-file update, including the "Maasvlakte" (which is new land, along the coast, reclaimed from the Northsea) into the shape describing the Netherlands.

Answer (score 1):

Querying the IANA time zone can be done in PowerShell.
The post
[How can I get the local system time zone as an IANA time zone ID on Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/1584967/how-can-i-get-the-local-system-time-zone-as-an-iana-time-zone-id-on-windows-10)
has this command:

```
[Windows.Globalization.Calendar,Windows.Globalization,ContentType=WindowsRuntime]::New().GetTimeZone()
```

If Windows is consistently getting your time-zone wrong, you
could disable time-zone auto-update by using
[sc.exe config](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/sc-config)
like the following (note the blank after `start=`) :

```
sc config tzautoupdate start= disabled
```

To set a fixed time-zone, use the
[tzutil command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/tzutil)
like this:

```
tzutil /s "Eastern Standard Time"
```

Comment: This is most likely a Microsoft bug. It may improve in future Windows updates, but for the moment my answer has at least a brute-force method.

Comment: I deleted my comment because I remembered that I hadn't checked the behavior of my newly acquired personal Windows machine, and that does set the correct time zone.  So before doing anything else I will look further into the hypothesis suggested by Ramhound, that the system administrators have done something to cause this behavior.

Comment: Try also to test Windows integrity by running the commands [Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html) and then [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: Another idea: Compare in the registry of both computers the contents of key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation`.

Answer (score 0):

do you have dual boot on these machines by any chance?

if you do windows works really bad with that, you need to set the new registry DWORD32 key named `RealTimeIsUniversal` in

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation
```

and set it to `1`

[this guide was quite helpful to me](https://www.howtogeek.com/323390/how-to-fix-windows-and-linux-showing-different-times-when-dual-booting/)

i might be wrong because it's usually the problem with assigning UTC time, not the timezone itself

Comment: There's no dual boot, I'm afraid.  Thanks for the tip, though, I've had that problem in the past.